# How to skip a hash if the fields contain Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+00A0 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am calling a remote service and the result is 
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+00A0 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII. How can I skip such responses and go to the next iteration of the loop.

Is there a way in which I can identify if a hash contains a field with such special characters.

Comment: please post some code which you're attempting this

Comment: I am making a call to a remote server and the response that I got contains such characters. I am unable to print the contents of the hash

Comment: Then post the code where you call that remote service

Comment: Can you just tell me how can I check if a string is encoded with UTF-8